# Why is ajax parsing json to the form "a=b&c=d"?

Tags: ajax, json, parsing

```
    $.ajax({
        url: '/metadata/hg_billing_cycle',
        data: {"a":"b", "c":"d"},
        datatype: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        type: 'POST',
        error: handleError,
    });
```

I'm using ruby on the server:

```
post "/" do
  puts "ummm: #{request.body.read}"
end
```

I get the following output:
`ummm: a=b&c=d` instead of `ummm : {"a":"b", "c":"d"}`. Why is it doing this?

Comment: That's normal `x-www-form-urlencoded` format for parameters.

Comment: What programming language are you using on the server? They should normally decode this for you, e.g. PHP will put them into `$_POST['a']` and `$_POST['c']`.

Comment: It's not JSON, it's a javascript object.

Comment: i'm using ruby for the server

Answer (score 1):

You are passing an object as the data parameter, from the [$.ajax docs](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

> data
>   Type: PlainObject or String
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

So your object is converted to a query string.
If you want to send json, then you'll have to well *send json*.
Convert your object to json (with [`JSON.stringify`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify)) and pass that as the data parameter.

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/metadata/hg_billing_cycle',
    data: JSON.stringify({"a":"b", "c":"d"}),
    datatype: "json",
    contentType: "application/json",
    type: 'POST',
    error: handleError,
});
```